# KnpPaginatorBundle to display max 5 navigation links visible at the begining

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to display max 5 navigation links visible when the page is loaded. Doesn't matter if I have more than 5 pages or not, it always starts with `1 2 3 Next >` rather than `1 2 3 4 5 Next >`

How do I achieve it with KnpPaginatorBundle?

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $query,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange because 5 it's the default value, did you changed it in the config section?

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5   # default page range used in pagination control
```

Documentation https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/paginator_configuration.md

Comment: I haven't check the config.yml for it but I'll check it on Monday when I get back to work. I checked its core files where there was 5 by default. I guess it is overridden somewhere else, maybe in config.yml by someone else.

Comment: It is set to 5 in every single file/place but I still get "1 2 3 Next" so on. Strange!

Comment: You can try to submit an issue on the github project. However let's make a test: you should try to change that value to 7, do you get the same output or the one you want?

Comment: I changed page_range to any number in every single place, but nothing seems to changing.